# simplecursoradapter listview filtering with toolbar searchview example

Tags: android

I have **MainActivity** which extends **AppCompatActivity** and it contains my menu items, and three **Tabs** which extends **Fragment** each containing my listview. How to I filter the listview using Searchview in my toolbar?. I have searched all round and found that which is using EditText to filter the listview or actually using searchview but not in a SimpleCursorAdapter with fragments. I don't want to implement that kind. How do I implement a filter that filters the listview (Using SimpleCursorAdapter in three diff tab fragments) as a user inputs text into the searchview?

Here is my **MainActivity** class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[]={"All","Index","Favourite"};
int Numboftabs =3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);
    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    if (pager != null) {
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    // Assigning the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    if (tabs != null) {
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width
    }
    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
SearchManager SManager =  (SearchManager)        getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchViewAction = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);     searchViewAction.setSearchableInfo(SManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
searchViewAction.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
return true;
}
```

And here is the my **Tab1** fragment

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
ListView listView;
Cursor cursor;
SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    DatabaseHelper dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getContext());
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DatabaseContract.SongBook.TABLE_NAME;
    final SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
   cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    String[] fromColumns = {DatabaseContract.SongBook._ID, DatabaseContract.SongBook.KEY_TITLE};
    int[] toView = {R.id.song_id, R.id.song_title};

    listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getContext(),         R.layout.songs_ltem_layout, cursor, fromColumns, toView,0);
    listAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor aCursor, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                String id = aCursor.getString(columnIndex);
                TextView textView = (TextView) view;
                textView.setText(String.format("%02d",     Integer.parseInt(id)));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
}
```

my **xml** files

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.katchoua.fgm_hymns.MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</menu>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/song_id"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="left"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dip"
    android:src="@drawable/musicno"
    android:layout_height="30dip" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/song_title"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want that as a user starts typing a character(s) depending on which tab fragement he/she is, the listview should be filtered dynamically according the text entered and returns back the original listview on closing the searchview.
Thanks for helping

Comment: first: `public static ListView listView;
public static Cursor cursor;` terrible idea ... also you are not closing cursor ... but back to topic : do a new query, swap cursor in adapter, close the old one and that's it

Comment: yeah, I get it. first of all, listview and cursor were not declared static, I was trying to use them outside their class before I declared them so. Anywhere, that's not actually where my problem is right now because I will remove the declarations as static...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to dynamically filter the listview using SearchView as the user searches instantly.
**Fragment:** having the listview, I did this:
All the imports may not be necessary for you because I just cut it out of my whole project, so you can ignore some

```
package com.xxx.yourpackagename.xxxx;    

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

ListView listView;
Cursor cursor;
View v;
SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
String[] fromColumns = {DatabaseContract.SongBook._ID, DatabaseContract.SongBook.KEY_TITLE};
int[] toView = {R.id.song_id, R.id.song_title};
DatabaseHelper dbhelper;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getContext());
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DatabaseContract.SongBook.TABLE_NAME;
    db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getContext(), R.layout.song_item_layout, cursor, fromColumns, toView, 0);
    listAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor aCursor, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                String id = aCursor.getString(columnIndex);
                TextView textView = (TextView) view;
                textView.setText(String.format("%03d", Integer.parseInt(id)));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Tab1.this.getActivity(), SongLyricsActivity.class);

                String title = "", content = "", favourite = "", songID = "";
                songID = Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(0));

                songID = String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(songID));
                title = cursor.getString(1);
                content = cursor.getString(2);
                favourite = Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(3));

                intent.putExtra(DatabaseContract.SongBook._ID, songID);
                intent.putExtra(DatabaseContract.SongBook.KEY_TITLE, title);
                intent.putExtra(DatabaseContract.SongBook.KEY_CONTENT, content);
                intent.putExtra(DatabaseContract.SongBook.KEY_IS_FAVORITE, favourite);
                Tab1.this.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
            //cursor.close();
        }
    });

    db.close();
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    searchView.setIconified(true);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager SManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchViewAction = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
    searchViewAction.setSearchableInfo(SManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchViewAction.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //listAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            try {

            db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
           // String mQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DatabaseContract.SongBook.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE _ID LIKE '%"+newText+ "%'";
            String[] selectionArgs;
            selectionArgs= new String[] {"%"+ newText + "%", "%"+ newText + "%" };
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + DatabaseContract.SongBook.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE _ID LIKE ? OR title LIKE ?", selectionArgs);
            SimpleCursorAdapter searchAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.song_item_layout, cursor, fromColumns, toView, 0);

                listView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
                TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.empty);
                text.setText("No Match found! \n Make sure you type in exact song number or song title...:)!");
                listView.setEmptyView(text);

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

   }
}
```

This performs a search by id or title populated on the listview from the database.
That's what worked for me, if I'm wrong anywhere, correct me on that if not, enjoy and upvote the answer for others to benefit from it...thanks and cheers...:)